# Strange results from OpenReadAsync() when reading data from Azure Blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm having a go at modifying an existing C# (dot net core) app that reads a type of binary file to use Azure Blob Storage.

I'm using Windows.Azure.Storage (8.6.0).

The issue is that this app reads the binary data from files from a Stream in very small blocks (e.g. 5000-6000 bytes). This reflects how the data is structured.

Example pseudo code:

```
var blocks = new List<byte[]>(); 
var numberOfBytesToRead = 6240;
var numberOfBlocksToRead = 1700;

using (var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
{
  stream.Seek(3000, SeekOrigin.Begin); // start reading at a particular position
  for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfBlocksToRead; i++)
  {
    byte[] traceValues = new byte[numberOfBytesToRead];
    stream.Read(traceValues, 0, numberOfBytesToRead);
    blocks.Add(traceValues);
  }
}`
```

If I try to read a 10mb file using OpenReadAsync(), I get invalid/junk values in the byte arrays after around 4,190,000 bytes.

- If I set StreamMinimumReadSize to 100Mb it works.
- If I read more data per block (e.g. 1mb) it works.

Some of the files can be more than 100Mb, so setting the StreamMinimumReadSize may not be the best solution.

What is going on here, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using OpenReadAsync version in case you still calling t.Result?

Comment: Good question. As mentioned in the post, I am using .net core and the Windows.Azure.Storage library which has async calls only. I guess the code was just from a test I was doing where I decided to invoke it synchronously. I have updated the code example with an await, but to be clear I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Have you also tried DownloadToStreamAsync blob method which is alternative to OpenReadAsync? 4Mb is default block size for blob download in case you hadn't specified other value in StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes property.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the DownloadToStreamAsync method and it works great. The only problem is that I may have to deal with a few files that are really big, and downloading the whole file to the stream may not be the best solution in this case.

Comment: You could pass the file stream instead of memory stream when using `DownloadToStreamAsync`. Or you could just use `DownloadToFileAsync`. If you want to increase the performance when downloading the big file, you could leverage `DownloadRangeToStream` and download the blob ranges in parallel, detailed code snippet you could follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810485/cloudblockblob-downloadtostream-vs-downloadrangetostream/41819508#41819508).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the invalid/junk values zeros? If so (and maybe even if not) check the return value from stream.Read. That method is not guaranteed to actually read the number of bytes that you ask it to. It can read less. In which case you are supposed to call it again in a loop, until it has read the total amount that you want. A quick web search should show you lots of examples of the necessary looping.

Comment: This was the issue. The existing application was reading from the stream but not checking that the number of bytes read was correct. For FileStream the problem never surfaced, but when working with the Azure Blobs and the OpenReadAsync() it became quickly apparent that you need to check the value returned from stream.Read.