# What is the efficient way to get data from ADLS Gen2 and bind it to Angular UI?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-data-lake

I am using Angular SPA project type for creating a client side application.

The data that i want to bind to UI is present in ADLS Gen2 storage.

> What is the efficient way to connect to ADLS Gen 2 and fetch the data?

I know there is blob SDK available but i am not sure how efficient it is as far as performance is concerned

Comment: Which way do you like to bind? Download the files locally or something like stream, then bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.If you prefer to use SDK, then the `blob SDK` is the right way to fetch data. Using the blob SDK, you can download the data to locally or get the data like stream.

2.If you want to download the data to local, then bind to UI, you can use [AZcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy), which provides high performance than `blob SDK`.

3.The last way, you can use sas-token with these data. Then you can get the data url with sas-token => then you can directly use these urls and bind to the UI. Here is the screenshot of generate sas-token and you can control the permission like read-only:

[image]

Assume you have this data in ADLS Gen2: test/image1.jgp, when you generate the sas-token, add this data to `Blob Service SAS URL` which is generated above, like below:

```
https://ADLS_Gen2_account.blob.core.windows.net/test/image1.jpg?sv=xxxx
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for replying in so detail. I know there is blob SDK available but i am not sure how efficient it is as far as performance is concerned

Comment: @SagarK, please let me know how do you do that? download the blobs to server side locally first, then bind it to UI, or use something like stream? and I also use see you label this question as c#, you want to use c# do it?

Comment: Yes i am using C# Azure blob sdk and using a stream to download and then de-serializing the data to object

Comment: @SagarK, if the file is small, you can directly use DownloadToStream method; if it's a little larger, you can use DownloadRangeToStream method with parallel to improve performance. For how to use DownloadRangeToStream with parallel, please refer to this [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810485/cloudblockblob-downloadtostream-vs-downloadrangetostream?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I appreciate your help

Comment: I have one question though, is it possible to query required data from blob. Meaning there is json file in blob but i only want certain column values from that json. is it possible? or di i need to get whole file in stream and then process

Comment: By using SDK, that's not possible. You should get the whole blob file in stream, or in string, then process.